# User email address into menu link in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a menu link within my WordPress site that pulls the logged in user's email address into the URL. For example, if the user is logged in as john@doe.com, I want their menu link to be https://example.com/?email=john@doe.com, whereas jane@smith.com would be https://example.com/?email=jane@smith.com.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I am not sure how expert are you in PHP and WordPress. but to create a menu like this, you need to google search two topics "Add custom menu item in WordPress menu by custom code" and "Get current user email address"
 then you can write your own function to generate that kind of menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this.

1. Find out the name of the menu you're trying to add into
2. Add this code snippet into your functions.php
   Note: You'll need to update the third line "primary" value to the name of the menu you're adding into

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $link = "https://example.com/";
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            $link .= "?email=" . $user_info->user_email;
        }
        $items .= '<li><a href="' . $link .'">Custom Text</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
?>
```

Comment: hmm I tried this but no luck, it made my website 503. I found the location of my menu was locations-menu-1.

Comment: I'm not too sure with your setup then. You must have a conflict somewhere else as this definitely works.